# member login; view & pay pledges

Tags: payment-processor, evaluating-civicrm, pledges

I run an organization that takes pledges from members. I am looking for software that would allow members to login to their accounts; view past and outstanding pledges and pay online for any money that is owed. Does CiviCRM do this? Thank you for any assistance that you can offer.

Answer (score 5):

CiviPledges can be set up so that
- a logged in contact can see their upcoming Pledges on their dashboard
- a contribution page can be set up as a self-service payments page

I set one up on the [Drupal demo site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm) so it should be there for a few hours before it flushes.

Dashboard is [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1)

Setting up a pledge is [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/pledge/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone)

The self-service payment is [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=3&pledgeId=4) but will only show if 'demo' contact has a pledge set up

If you need to add a Pledge to contact called 'demo' you can do so [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/pledge?reset=1&action=add&cid=202&context=pledge)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I am having difficulty logging in to the demo account. I created a new account, but I cannot login.

Comment: It generally says in a fairly obvious place to login using demo/demo - does that not show to you?

Comment: sorry i see my link didn't help. go here http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: I created a demo account but the login did not work. I tried it several time without success. The error message is "The username cglassman has not been activated or is blocked".

Comment: you don't need to create an account. just go to the link i gave you and enter demo as the user and demo as the password