# how to add a Pledge to contact

Tags: pledges, civipledge, simple-donate-form

**Hi,
 How do I  add a Pledge to contact so that he may view & pay pledges thru the  self-service payments page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the manual before asking this question?

As per my reply [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/member-login-view-pay-pledges)

CiviPledges can be set up so that

- a logged in contact can see their upcoming Pledges on their dashboard
- a contribution page can be set up as a self-service payments page

Setting up a pledge is [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/pledge/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone)

The contacts Dashboard is [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1)

The self-service payment is [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=3&pledgeId=4) but will only show if 'demo' contact has a pledge set up

If you need to add a Pledge to contact called 'demo' you can do so [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/pledge?reset=1&action=add&cid=202&context=pledge)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Great. Please help the system work well. Accept the answer. And help me ;-) by giving it a +1